# I want my h4,h2 and p tag to change input when I click them

Tags: reactjs

[My Component Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyVmG.png)

I want my h4,h2 and p tag to change input when I click them

How can I simply do that with reactjs ?

```
    export default function requestCard(props) {
  return (
    <div className="Card">
      <div className="Card-Top">
        <div className="Top-Left">
          <IoIosRadioButtonOn />
          <h4>{props.data.Status}</h4>
        </div>
        <div className="Top-Right">
          <h4>{props.data.Date}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="Card-Middle">
        <h2>{props.data.CutStyle}</h2>
        <p>{props.data.client}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="Card-Bottom">
        <img src={props.data.Picture} alt="new photos" />
        <h2>{props.data.name}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by change input? as in there value should change when you click on it?

Comment: Where is your input?

Comment: When I click the h4  or h2 texts I want that area to become an input area.

Comment: I couldn't describe it I quess. I want those h4 tag to become an input tag :D I couldn't do I tried for like 2 hours :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follow (For example for Status)

```
const [statusEdit, setStatusEdit] = useState(false);
const [status, setStatus] = useState(props.data.Status);
```

Then in return section write as follow:

```
 <div className="Top-Left">
    <IoIosRadioButtonOn />
    {
       statusEdit ? 
            <input value={status} onChange={(e)=>{setStatus(e.target.value)}}  onKeyDown={(e) => {if(e.keyCode  === 13) setStatusEdit(false)}} />:
            <h4 onClick={() => setStatusEdit(true)} >{status}</h4>
    }
 </div>
```

Comment: Line 18:31:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  gave that error.    I change to === but  the value props.data.Status didn't show up at the area. and before I change == to === data did not showed on the screen

Comment: Did you try my latest edit? please check. I've checked it and it's working.

Comment: Voov yes I tried right now and its working  thank you so muuch now ım gonna try to understand and implement it to other components thank you soo much